# Getting "Missing required field Principal" when adding policy to S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-policy

I'm following [amplify docs](https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/storage) on how to configure Storage. When adding the policy to the document I'm getting the following error:

```
Missing required field Principal
```

I'm not sure why...?

Policy document (from the docs):

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:DeleteObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::{enter bucket name}/public/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::{enter bucket name}/protected/${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::{enter bucket name}/private/${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}/*"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow"
        },
        {
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::{enter bucket name}/uploads/*"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow"
        },
        {
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::{enter bucket name}/protected/*"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow"
        },
        {
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "s3:prefix": [
                        "public/",
                        "public/*",
                        "protected/",
                        "protected/*",
                        "private/${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}/",
                        "private/${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}/*"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::{enter bucket name}"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Please include your policy, with sensitive ID's redacted :)

Comment: Added. Bucket name replaced.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You're missing the `Principal` block, which defines **to whom** you're granting the permissions. This is the counterpart of the `Resource` block, which defines **what** the permissions are for. Take a look at [the example bucket policies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html) e.g.:

```
{
  "Version":"2012-10-17",
  "Statement":[
    {
      "Sid":"PublicRead",
      "Effect":"Allow",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action":["s3:GetObject"],
      "Resource":["arn:aws:s3:::examplebucket/*"]
    }
  ]
}
```

Grants read-only permissions to everyone (`*`).

Comment: "Principal" seems not be mentioned at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_examples_s3_rw-bucket-console.html but yet is needed otherwise it throws an error. It's what makes the overly convoluted docs such a joy.

Comment: @Epirocks agreed that it’s misleading, but note that principal isn’t *always* required. Namely, you can write a policy like the one linked then attach it to an entity (like a user) to grant that entity (and any others to which you attach the policy) those permissions. For OP it’s required because the policy is attached to the bucket whose access it’s limiting, not to the entity (the implicit principal) accessing the bucket.